# SIMD3 Extension with default implementations

Tags: swift, protocols, generic-programming, swift-protocols, swift5

I have a few `protocols` for `vectors` used across my app. They have some `default implementations` in `extensions`, so that I can have all added functionality implemented for all `types of vectors`. Now I would like to extend `SIMD3` with `Scalar == Double`, to implement Vector3D protocol. `Swift` is telling me that if I specify type of `Scalar` in extension, then I need to also add all dependencies of `Vector3D` for this type. I don't know why this is not happening automatically when I choose associated type of `SIMD3`, but ok. So now I have something like this:

```
import UIKit
import simd

protocol DividableByInt {
    static func / (lhs: Self, rhs: Int) -> Self
}
protocol HasBasicinitializer {
    init()
}
protocol BasicMathOperations {
    static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    static func - (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    static func * (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    static func / (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}
protocol Vector: BasicMathOperations, DividableByInt, HasBasicinitializer {
    associatedtype Scalar: (SIMDScalar & FloatingPoint)
    static var zero: Self { get }
    static func calculate(_ lhs: Self, _ rhs: Self, _ operation: (Scalar, Scalar) -> Scalar) -> Self
    static func calculate(_ lhs: Self, _ rhs: Scalar, _ operation: (Scalar, Scalar) -> Scalar) -> Self
    func allAxesValues() -> [Scalar]
}
extension Vector {
    static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self { return calculate(lhs, rhs, +) }
    static func - (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self { return calculate(lhs, rhs, -) }
    static func * (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self { return calculate(lhs, rhs, *) }
    static func / (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self { return calculate(lhs, rhs, /) }
    static func * (lhs: Self, rhs: Scalar) -> Self { return calculate(lhs, rhs, *) }
    static func / (lhs: Self, rhs: Scalar) -> Self { return calculate(lhs, rhs, /) }
    static func / (lhs: Self, rhs: Int) -> Self { return calculate(lhs, Scalar(rhs), /) }
}
protocol Vector3D: Vector {
    init(x: Scalar, y: Scalar, z: Scalar)
    var x: Scalar { get }
    var y: Scalar { get }
    var z: Scalar { get }
}
extension Vector3D {
    func allAxesValues() -> [Scalar] {
        return [x, y, z]
    }
    static func calculate(_ lhs: Self, _ rhs: Self, _ operation: (Scalar, Scalar) -> Scalar) -> Self {
        return Self(x: operation(lhs.x, rhs.x), y: operation(lhs.y, rhs.y), z: operation(lhs.z, rhs.z))
    }
    static func calculate(_ lhs: Self, _ rhs: Scalar, _ operation: (Scalar, Scalar) -> Scalar) -> Self {
        return Self(x: operation(lhs.x, rhs), y: operation(lhs.y, rhs), z: operation(lhs.z, rhs))
    }
}

extension SIMD3: Vector3D where Scalar == Double {}

extension SIMD3: HasBasicinitializer {}
extension SIMD3: DividableByInt where Scalar == Double {}
extension SIMD3: Vector where Scalar == Double {
    static let zero = SIMD3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
}
extension SIMD3: BasicMathOperations where Scalar == Double {}
```

Everything works automatically, except the last one thing:

```
extension SIMD3: BasicMathOperations where Scalar == Double {}
```

The compiler says:

```
Type 'SIMD3<Scalar>' does not conform to protocol 'BasicMathOperations'
```

But since I added

```
extension SIMD3: Vector where Scalar == Double
```

it should have all needed methods implemented already, and be able to proceed. Protocol `DividableByInt` is inherited almost in the same way, and it can work with the implementation from `Vector extension`. Why is that `BasicMathOperations` can't use methods implemented in `Vector extension`?

I know I could resolve this by adding

```
extension SIMD3: BasicMathOperations where Scalar == Double {
    static func + (lhs: SIMD3, rhs: SIMD3) -> SIMD3 { return calculate(lhs, rhs, +) }
    static func - (lhs: SIMD3, rhs: SIMD3) -> SIMD3 { return calculate(lhs, rhs, -) }
    static func * (lhs: SIMD3, rhs: SIMD3) -> SIMD3 { return calculate(lhs, rhs, *) }
    static func / (lhs: SIMD3, rhs: SIMD3) -> SIMD3 { return calculate(lhs, rhs, /) }
}
```

but I don't want to double this code, since it's already implemented in `extension Vector`, and it should be used from there place instead.

In the end I just want to extend `SIMD3` to implement `Vector3D`. If needed with `Scalar == Double` or for any type of Scalar of possible.

---

Looks like the problem is because SIMD3 already has implemented functions like +, -, /, * and compiler can't determine which one to choose. I could remove default implementation from `Vector` and this would resolve the issue for SIMD3, but then I would need to separately implement it for all other types that conforms to Vector. Im using this also for `SCNVector3` and `CGPoint`. I don't know what is better. Maybe there is some better solution, so that I can just have this implemented for all other types but SIMD3?

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I have found one better solution. I moved default implementation of `BasicMathOperations` from `extension Vector` to separate protocol, and then I added inheritance to this new protocol to all types that conform to Vector, except for SIMD3.

```
// Adds default implementation for BasicMathOperation
protocol VectorWithDefaultImplementationForBasicMathOperations: Vector {}

extension VectorWithDefaultImplementationForBasicMathOperations {
    static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self { return calculate(lhs, rhs, +) }
    static func - (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self { return calculate(lhs, rhs, -) }
    static func * (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self { return calculate(lhs, rhs, *) }
    static func / (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self { return calculate(lhs, rhs, /) }
}

extension CGPoint: VectorWithDefaultImplementationForBasicMathOperations {}
extension SCNVector3: VectorWithDefaultImplementationForBasicMathOperations {}
```

If anyone know better solution, please let me know, but I think this is already pretty fine.